# how to write a map reduce for the following

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I have the following data

```
Name Year  score
A    1996  84
A    1997  65
A    1996  76
A    1998  78
A    1998  65
B    1998  53
B    1996  98
B    1996  83
B    1996  54
```

I want output as follows

```
Name Year  max_score
A    1996  84
B    1996  98
```

How can I write python map reduce code for this job?

I can create NAME and YEAR as a single key and score as value will work.

But is there any other way to handle this.

Comment: Do you just want only these two rows as output?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You've apparently got an approach that works, but you're looking for a better way? Can you show us some code?

Comment: Can you clarify the question. My understanding is that you want a row for each Name corresponding to the row in which they have their highest score. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all your years and scores are positive:

```
from collections import defaultdict

mapping = defaultdict( lambda: (0,0) )
with open(datafile) as f:
     for line in f:
         name,year,score = line.split()
         try:
            year = int(year)
            score = int(score)
         except ValueError:
            continue

         if score > mapping[name][1]:
            mapping[name] = year,score
```

Or slightly more terse, but less robust against errors:

```
from collections import defaultdict

mapping = defaultdict( lambda: (0,0) )
with open(datafile) as f:
     f.readline() #header.  Don't need it.
     for line in f:
         name,year,score = line.split()
         if int(score) > mapping[name][1]:
            mapping[name] = int(year),int(score)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
def mapper(key, value):
    name, year, score = value.split()
    yield name, (year, score)

def reducer(name, values):
    yield name, max(values, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```